# How can I make a card with the header fixed in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have a type card:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class='card'>
     <div class='card-header'>
      <div class='row'>
       <div class='col'>
        <h5 class='mb-0'>Element</h5>
       </div>
       <div class='col'>
        <p class='text-right mb-0'>n</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
      <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
      <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
     <ul>
     <div class='card-footer'>
      <div class='input-group'>
       <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='New item'>
       <div class='input-group-append'>
        <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='button'> + </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The more items are added, the more the header where the number of items comes from is moved.

How can I make it stay in position when the items are more?

I tried sticky-top but it's stuck all the way to the top so it has a margin or padding on top.

Answer (score 1):

that would be my approach:

basicaly: set position:relative to parent element (.card) and position:fixed to child element (.card-header)

```css
.card{
  position: relative; /* all child elements gets positioned relative to this element */
}
.card-header{
  position: fixed; /* stay fixed on top */
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1; /* needed to stay above other elements */
}
.list-group{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col'>
                <h5 class='mb-0'>Element</h5>
            </div>
            <div class='col'>
                <p class='text-right mb-0'>n</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 4</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 5</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 6</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 7</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 8</li>
        <li class='list-group-item'>Item 9</li>
    <ul>
    <div class='card-footer'>
        <div class='input-group'>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='New item'>
            <div class='input-group-append'>
                <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='button'> + </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply css to your ul for fixed card header when item increase. You can change ul height as suitable as you.

```
.list-group-flush{height:400px;overflow-y:auto;}
```

```css
  .list-group-flush{height:400px;overflow-y:auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class='card'>
        <div class='card-header'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col'>
                    <h5 class='mb-0'>Element</h5>
                </div>
                <div class='col'>
                    <p class='text-right mb-0'>n</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 1</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 2</li>
            <li class='list-group-item'>Item 3</li>
        <ul>
        <div class='card-footer'>
            <div class='input-group'>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='New item'>
                <div class='input-group-append'>
                    <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='button'> + </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```